# Sybase DB Error : Database driver error...Send failed

Tags: c++, sybase, win64

When I am trying to execute a simple select query (from C++ application , Sybase DB)  , I get this error .

Database driver error...Send failed

Database driver error...

Function Name : Execute

There is nothing wrong in the query

If I try to execute this same query , from the console query execution goes fine and get the result .

Searched online, no info about this . Whether you guys faced this problem ever,Or what are all the other parameters I can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is . This error comes when DB client (C++ app) not able to send request to server because one more is connection is still open and has some pending results , hence the error. I have closed connections explicitly , that solves the problem